# Magnific-popup не работает на одной странице

Tags: html, jquery, css, magnific

На сайте 4 страницы идентичны, а главная отличается, вот на ней и не работает `magnific-popup`, на странице форму не скрывает, при клике не отображает. На остальных страницах норм. Код не вставляю, придется много вставлять, [ссылку](http://videoproduction.aleksandernitchenko.ru/) оставлю. Подскажите, где я что упустил? Проблема только с формой, видео и тектовое всплывающее работает на всех страницах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на главной не подлючен magnific скрипт. Проблема в этом.